# Count doesn't consider the newly inserted record

Tags: c#, linq

After inserting the first record, the count shows 0 even after the insert. I can see the the record inserted as soon as SaveContext()
is executed. So looks like userChangeRequestApprovalRepository isnt refreshed with the newly inserted data.
Is it appropriate to do count + 1 like the statement below instead

```
userChangeRequestApprovalRepository.Where(x => x.UserChangeRequestId == userChangeRequest.Id).Count() + 1;
```

Code

```
 InsertUserChangeRequestApproval(userChangeRequest);
  SaveContext();

 var numberOfAprovals = userChangeRequestApprovalRepository.Where(x => x.UserChangeRequestId == userChangeRequest.Id).Count();
```

insert method

```
    private void InsertUserChangeRequestApproval(UserChangeRequest userChangeRequest)
            {
                UserChangeRequestApproval userChangeRequestApproval = new UserChangeRequestApproval()
                {
                    UserChangeRequestId = userChangeRequest.Id,
                    ApprovedByAuthUserId = userChangeRequest.ChangedByAuthUserId,
                    ApprovedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    IsActive = true

                };
                UserChangeRequestApprovalRepository.Insert(userChangeRequestApproval);


            }

 public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
```

SaveContext method

```
  public int SaveContext()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The code for the whole method

```
 public IdentityResult ApproveUserChangeRequest(UserChangeRequest userChangeRequest, int approvedByAuthUserId, string authApplicationName)
        {
            var userChangeRequestRepository = UserChangeRequestRepository.GetAllAsList();
            var userChangeRequestApprovalRepository = UserChangeRequestApprovalRepository.GetAllAsList();
            var appSettingRepository = AppSettingRepository.GetAllAsList();
            var clientCompanyContactRepository = ClientCompanyContactRepository.GetAllAsList();
            var applicationUserRepo = ApplicationUserRepo.GetAllAsList();
           // int approvedByAuthUserID = GetApprovedByUserId(authApplicationName, approvedByAuthUserName);

            // Check if UserChangeRequest is still Pending
            bool isUserChangeRequestPending = userChangeRequestRepository.Any(x => x.Id == userChangeRequest.Id && x.ChangeStatus == "Pending");

            if (isUserChangeRequestPending && approvedByAuthUserId > 0)
            {
                // Inserting record in the UserChangeRequestApproval table
                   InsertUserChangeRequestApproval(userChangeRequest);
                   SaveContext();

                using (var userTransaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var securityTransaction = _securityContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Get the Number of approval required for Internal and External Users
                            int? internalApprovalsRequired = GetApprovals("InternalUserChangeRequestApprovalsRequired", appSettingRepository);
                            int? externalApprovalsRequired = GetApprovals("ExternalUserChangeRequestApprovalsRequired", appSettingRepository);

                            //Get the name of the application the auth user belongs to
                            var authUserApplicationName = GetApplicationName(userChangeRequest.AuthUserId);

                            //Get the Number of approvals for the request

                            var numberOfAprovals = userChangeRequestApprovalRepository.Where(x => x.UserChangeRequestId == userChangeRequest.Id).Count();

                            //If the number of approvals is equal or greater than the Approvals required then Update AppUser or Contact details
                            if ((authUserApplicationName == "ArgentexTrader" && numberOfAprovals >= internalApprovalsRequired) || (authUserApplicationName == "ArgentexClient" && numberOfAprovals >= externalApprovalsRequired))
                            {
                                //Updating the clientcontact table
                                UpdateClientContact(userChangeRequest, clientCompanyContactRepository);


                                //Updating the auth user table
                                UpdateAuthUser(userChangeRequest);


                                //Updating the IdentityDB user table
                                UpdateIdentityDBUser(userChangeRequest, applicationUserRepo);

                                //Updating the UserChangeRequest table
                                userChangeRequest.ChangeStatus = "Approved";
                                UserChangeRequestRepository.Update(userChangeRequest);

                                SaveContext();
                                userTransaction.Commit();
                                securityTransaction.Commit();
                                return IdentityResult.Success;
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            userTransaction.Rollback();
                            securityTransaction.Rollback();
                            _logger.Error(ex);
                            return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description = ex.Message });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Without knowing what methods `InsertUserChangeRequestApproval` and `SaveContext` do it impossible to answer.

Comment: And what `UserChangeRequestApprovalRepository.Insert` does. You're asking people to guess what your `userChangeRequestApprovalRepository` does. Most likely it violates how EF works one way or another, they way all "generic" repositories do.

Comment: We need more code to understand what's going on here. If you are adding records to a DataGridView or something similar, then maybe you should call dataGridView.EndEdit() before calling the count query

Comment: You have to replace insert() to add() method. Otherwise everything seems right.

Comment: @Niteen those are methods in the OP's custom class and `Insert()` does call `DbSet<>.Add()`. Something is obviously *not* right

Comment: I have updated the post with the complete method as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I focused only "InsertUserChangeRequestApproval(userChangeRequest)" and "SaveContext()" those methods.

Comment: @Tom take some time and look at your code now and think how it would look **without** the repository simply aliasing the methods of a DbContext. What would it look if you *removed* the manual transactions? `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. What would it look if there was only *one* repository? A DbContext can have *multiple* DbSet, there's no reason to use multiple contexts/repositories, no reason to use multiple transactions.

Comment: @Tom transactions implement IDisposable too, so all you need is to wrap them in a `using` block and call `Commit`. Although you wouldn't need them if you used EF properly

Comment: @Tom what does `AppSettingRepository.GetAllAsList()` return? Unless it's an IQueryable it's loading everything in memory and won't reflect any changes to the database itself. It's also loading a lot of stuff that's not needed - LINQ to EF generates queries that only load the objects that are needed, while `GetAllList` seems to be loading everything, useful or not.

Comment: @Tom finally - two transactions means either one real and one no-op (SQL Server doesn't have nested transactions) or two *different* connections, different transactions that *don't* see the other's changes until they are committed.

Comment: Fortunately, each DbSet has a Local property that acts like the DbSet itself, but it reflect all in-memory operations.
You can use Local to add entities.

Comment: What do i use instead of AppSettingRepository.GetAllAsList() or do i call it after the insert method

Comment: @Tom those are just a few of the reasons that make "generic" repositories an antipattern. They create a *lower* level API than the high-level abstraction offered by the ORM (EF, NH) and thus break it

Comment: @Tom just remove that class altogether, use a *single* context with the sets you want and write proper EF code, that loads only what it needs. The code is too convoluted right now, with a *lot* of methods missing, eg `GetApprovals` or `UpdateIdentityDBUser`. Most of them can become methods on your single DbContext-derived class, no extra repository is needed. If you get an error saying that something can't be translated to SQL, fix the code, don't load everything in memory to bypass the error